# Angular 2 validation with parsleyjs for decimal values

Tags: angular, parsley.js

I am trying to validate an input field in my *Angular 2* application using *parsleyjs* so that user can enter values like

> 1 or 1.1 or 1.11 or 1.11 or 1.111 ot 1.1111

and it should pass validation. I have tried something like this

```
<div class="form-group row">
          <label for="platformyposition" class="col-md-6 col-form-label">Platform Y Position (mm) <span class="required">*</span></label>
          <div class="col-md-5">
            <input class="form-control input-transparent " id="platformyposition" type="text" formControlName="platformyposition"  data-parsley-trigger="blur"
              required="required" data-parsley-pattern="[0-9]*(\.?[0-9]{4}$)?"/>
         </div>
</div>
```

but it is now only passing validation when I enter 4 digits after the digit and not for the other condition I mentioned above. Can somebody please help me get this correct!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is to change `data-parsley-pattern` :

```
[0-9]*(\.?[0-9]{1,4}$)?
```

`{4}` this will check exact 4 decimal
`{1,4}` and this will check 1 to 4 times decimal